# C# - Pushing Enter in MessageBox triggers control KeyUp Event

Tags: c#, winforms

System: Windows7 Pro, Visual Studio 2010, C#

I have a textbox: `textBox1`
I set its event:

```
textBox1.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyUp);

private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid data", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    } 
}
```

It works fine, the problem is, when the data entered is invalid, and thus the `MessageBox` is shown, when i hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on the `MessageBox` OK Button, it also triggers the `textBox1_KeyUp`, which causes the `MessageBox` to show up again.
So, it triggers the `MessageBox` OK button, which causes it to disappear, and also triggers the `textbox_keyUp` which then causes the messagebox to show up again.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, the message box responds to the key down event.  So should your TextBox.  Use the KeyDown event instead, problem solved.  Also solves the annoying BEEP the user normally hears.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) {
            button1.PerformClick();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But this is my problem, i dont want it to trigger both, i want it to trigger only the MessageBox button

Comment: Not sure what you mean by comment out, but now that you mentioned it, what does SuppressKeyPress does? Maybe it stops multiple events from firing when holding the button down? just guessing

Answer (score 1):

i solved it for listview, it can work for textbox:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox1.enable = false;
        button1.PerformClick();
        textBox1.enable = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controls will only fire events if they have focus. So in your case you're executing button click with focus still on your text box and that's why you can't use enter on the message box. The solution is to add following code inside button1_Click method:

```
var btn = sender as Button;
btn.Focus();
```

This time focus will be set on the button so if you hit enter on the message box no event will fire for text box

Comment: I can use enter the message box. In fact, what i want is to use enter ONLY in the MessageBox, not in BOTH the MessageBox and my button

Comment: Okay , but what I was trying to say is that with setting focus on the button you can use enter on your message box and it will not trigger text box event again and again