# MessageBox does not suppress keyboard Enter key

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a button which, on `Click` event I made some validations upon some `TextBox`es in my `Form`.
If a `TextBox` does not pass the validation, then I force the `Focus` to it (user must enter some characters in that `TextBox`). My `TextBox` class already have some code to go to the next control if user will press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

MyTextBox.cs class

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox(){
        KeyUp += MyTextBox_KeyUp;
        KeyDown += MyTextBox_KeyDown;
    }

    private void MyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // This will suppress Blink sound
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }

    private void MyTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return))
        {
            // This will go to the next control if Enter will be pressed.
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }
    }
}
```

Form's button click event:

```
private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // txtName is based on MyTextBox class
    if(txtName.Text.Length == 0){
        MessageBox.Show("Name field could not be empty! Please fill the Name!", "Error Message",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        // If I Click the OK button, txtName will stay focused in the next line,
        // but if I press Enter key, it will go to the next control.
        txtName.Focus();
        return;
    }
    // Some other validations ...
    // Calling printing method ...
}
```

How do I stop the loosing focus on my textboxes when user hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in that `MessageBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MessageBox can cause re-entrancy problems in some occasions. This is a classic one.

In this specific case, when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed to send a confirmation to the dialog, the `KeyUp` event *re-enters* the message loop and is dispatched to the active control. The TextBox, here, because of this call: `txtName.Focus();`.

When this happens, the code in the TextBox's `KeyUp` event handler is triggered again, causing a `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");`.

There are different ways to solve this. In this case, just use the `TextBox.KeyDown` event to both suppress the `Enter` key and move the focus:

```
private void MyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
}
```

Also, see (for example):

[Pushing Enter in MessageBox triggers control KeyUp Event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538909/7444103)
[MessageBox causes key handler to ignore SurpressKeyPress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39533520/7444103)

as different methods to handle similar situations.