# How to prevent keystroke in child form reaching parent form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that, upon user request, opens a child form, like so --

```
private void toolTrim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form = new TrimOptions();
    form.ShowDialog();
    if (form.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      //code;
    }
{
```

This child form has a button called `btnOk` and its property `AcceptButton` set to `btnOk`. This means that, when the Enter key is pressed in the child form, it's as if you had clicked on the Ok button, and this code executes.

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();
}
```

The problem is that, when the child form closes, the Enter key that was used to close the child form is captured by the DataGridView in the *parent* form.

```
    private void filesDataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return) //execution stops here if breakpointed
```

There's a legitimate use for that, but only when the DGV has focus, not when some child form of this form has focus.

So, how to prevent keystrokes in a child form from "bubbling up" to a parent form?

Comment: This should never happen. Something else is at work here to produce that behavior. Not sure if it is related but you don't need to call Close after you set the DialogResult.OK to the form DialogResult property. The form will close automatically. Do you have code in the Form_Closing or Forn_Closed events?

Comment: The problem is that the DGV *does* have the focus.  KeyUp is for games, always favor KeyDown.  Or give another control the focus before ShowDialog()

Comment: [MessageBox does not suppress keyboard Enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59069497/7444103). Read the notes, then do as suggested in the comment above (i.e., only the KeyUp event bubbles up in this context, not KeyDown).

Comment: @HansPassant I had use KeyUp because I read that KeyDown repeats while key is held down and I expected to have to do a lot of work to avoid accidental key repeating, but I forgot there's a pause before the keystroke starts repeating. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Steve's advice, I removed the `Close();` having learned that setting `DialogResult` to any value other than None will close the window.

Following Hans Passant's advice to use `KeyDown` instead of `KeyUp`, I realized I had a mixture of KeyDowns and KeyUps. He was also correct, of course, that indeed the DGV had focus. I made them all KeyDowns, and my problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

the other solution would be before opening modal you can disable the parent form once dialog is closed you can enable the parent form, so key up event does not fire.